# Tomcat's maximum capacity

Tags: performance, tomcat

Our development team has 14 small applications deployed to Tomcat 5.5 currently (moving to 6.0 shortly).  I say small because the number of users for each app is low.  I'm wondering what performance metrics and indicators I should be looking at to decide when it is time to introduce an additional application server.

Aside from memory usage and CPU utilization, what should I look out for?  How do I know when it's time to scale up or out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would be monitoring:

- average HTTP response times
- output of `iostat` (or whatever counterpart on Windows if you're running Win)
- network saturation
- possible thread deadlocks (not sure how multithreaded your app is)
- database load, if there is one

Generally it is hard to advise when to scale up/out, each situation is different. But it is always worth to have a plan - in case if your customer base will double in the next few months.

Scaling up is usually cheaper (to a point). I recommend [this site](http://highscalability.com/) for scalability-related stuff.

Comment: Thanks.  FYI for those wondering - I've learned that the Windows equivalent of iostat is perfmon.  Type "perfmon" into the run dialog to start it up.